# Showing IST (Indian Standard Time) in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, timezone

Below is my ASP (not ASP.NET) code:

```
<%
days = day(now)
    if len(days) <> 2 then 
        days = "0"&days 
    END IF
    months = month(now)
    if len(months) <> 2 then 
        months ="0"&months
    end if
    min = dateadd("n",2,now)
    hr = dateadd("h",-5,now)
    Hrs = hour(hr)
    if len(Hrs) <> 2 then 
        Hrs ="0"&Hrs
    end if
    Mins = minute(min)
    if len(Mins) <> 2 then 
        Mins ="0"&Mins
    end if
    Secs = second(now)
    if len(Secs) <> 2 then 
        Secs ="0"&Secs
    end if
    datess = year(now)&"-"&months&"-"&days&"T"&Hrs&":"&Mins&":"&Secs

    response.write(datess) %>
```

The output is the server time (server hosted in UK). Now I want to convert this into IST (Indian Standard Time). How can I do that in Classic ASP?

Comment: Logic says that you should take UTC time and add time to that UTC time according to time zone like 5:30 hr for IST I guess.

Answer (score 1):

ASP VBScript doesn't understand the concept of timezones just what the current server time is.  JScript ASP does, and luckily enough you can mix and match your scripting languages in ASP.

This will use JScript to get the UTC date and time into a format that VBScript can then understand and operate on:

```
<script  language="javascript" runat="server">

    var od = new Date();
    var nd = od;
    var s = nd.getUTCDate() + "/";
    s += (nd.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/";
    s += nd.getUTCFullYear() + " ";
    s += (nd.getUTCHours()) + ":";
    s += nd.getUTCMinutes() + ":";
    s += nd.getUTCSeconds();
    datUTC = s;

</script>
<% 

Response.Write(FormatDateTime(datUTC, 3))

%>
```

Once you have UTC, then you can apply your own rules to convert that to IST predictably.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the correct number of hours (GMT + 5:30) to the current UK time.

```
DateAdd("n",330,NOW()) --adds 5 1/2 hours to current time
```

You'll need to do it within a function that also allows for the fact Indian Standard Time doesn't operate Daylight Saving Time in the same way the UK does (during British summer time). So for certain parts of the year you'd only add 4 1/2 hours on.

Example function:

```
<% 
offset = 330 '5 1/2 hours in minutes

' tell us what date you want 
currentUkDateTime = NOW()

' find first Sunday in April 
for i = 1 to 7 
    if weekday("4/" & i & "/" & year(d))=1 then 
        startDST = cdate("4/" & i & "/" & year(d)) 
    end if 
next 

' find last Sunday in October 
for i = 31 to 25 step -1 
    if weekday("10/" & i & "/" & year(d))=1 then 
        endDST = cdate("10/" & i & "/" & year(d)) 
    end if 
next 

' subtract hour from offset if within DST 
if cdate(od) >= startDST and cdate(od) < endDST then 
    offset = offset - 1 
end if 

currentISTDateTime = dateadd("n", offset, currentUkDateTime) 

Response.Write("Current = " & currentUkDateTime & "<Br>UTC = " & currentISTDateTime ) 
%>
```

(With help from [classicasp.aspfaq.com](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-gmt-time.html))

Comment: How would you determien when the UK is currently in BST?

Comment: Find first Sunday in April and find last Sunday in October, then determine if requested datetime is within this period and add/subtract 1 hour as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

In ASP you have something called LOCALE, check this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229690

However... be sure you want to go that route, I you go check if you are happy with:
- currency
- datetime
- and LAST but NOT lease the decimal separator.... in some LOCALES that separator is a comma (as opposed to US where it is a .) you could end up with SELECT * FROM article WHERE price > 3,14 -> big error to parameters provided (the LOCALE could change PI (3.14) into 3,14 this can be avoided but ... internationalization in classic ASP is quite 'simple'...